# Boolean filter using a timestamp value on a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe created from a `.csv` document. Since one of the columns has dates, I have used pandas `read_csv` with `parse_dates`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('CSVdata.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", parse_dates=['Dates_column'])
```

The dates range from 2012 to 2016. I want to crate a sub-dataframe, containing only the rows from 2014.

The only way I have managed to do this, is with two subsequent Boolean filters:

```
df_a = df[df.Dates_column>pd.Timestamp('2014')]  # To create a dataframe from 01/Jan/2014 onwards.

df = df_a[df_a.Dates_column<pd.Timestamp('2015')] # To remove all the values after 01/jan/2015
```

Is there a way of doing this in one step, more efficiently?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`dt` accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor):

```
df = df[df.Dates_column.dt.year == 2014]
```